# SQLAlchemy default PostgreSQL ARRAY behavior

Tags: python, arrays, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table I am creating and interacting with using the SQLAlchemy expression engine and I am needing to be able to fetch the values from the `ARRAY` column as a python `tuple` not a `list`. Since the constructor for `ARRAY` columns allows you to specify if you want the values as tuples, I ended up just reflecting the table out of the database, looking for `ARRAY` columns, replacing them with an `ARRAY` column that has the appropriate keyword argument and then using that to construct expressions. Like so:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, String, MetaData, select

def swapArrayColumns(table):
    new_cols = []
    for col in table.columns:
        if isinstance(col.type, ARRAY):
            new_cols.append(Column(col.name, ARRAY(String, as_tuple=True)))
        else:
        new_cols.append(Column(col.name, col.type))
    return new_cols

engine = create_engine('postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname')    
meta = MetaData()
table = Table('table_name', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
new_cols = swapArrayColumns(table)

# delete old meta since we are re-mapping table
del meta
meta = MetaData()
new_table = Table('table_name', meta, *new_cols)

# Now I can use the new table object to generate expressions
sel = select([new_table]).where(new_table.c.foo == 'bar')
rows = list(engine.execute(sel))
```

Since this gets used quite a lot, I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way of accomplishing this same thing perhaps by creating a custom sqlalchemy dialect that just does this for me. All I really want is my `ARRAY` columns to come back as python `tuple`s by default.

Answer (score 1):

could look at using a [custom sqlalchemy type](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/custom_types.html#augmenting-existing-types), something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY,
class Tuple(types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = ARRAY

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return list(value)

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return tuple(value)
```

and in the model itself (using declarative):

```
class MyModel(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(Tuple)
```

Another way perhaps would be to sub-class ARRAY:

```
from  sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY as PG_ARRAY
class ARRAY(PG_ARRAY):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PG_ARRAY, self ).__init__(*args, *kwargs)
        self.as_tuple = True
```

Comment: I guess the problem is that the tables are dynamically created, (sometimes with array columns, sometimes without) and, because of that, I'm not using the ORM parts of SQLAlchemy, just the table reflection and SQL expression generator parts. The ideal would just be to override this when I create the `engine` that I use to connect to the database (so that every `ARRAY` I fetched from the database was a turned into a Python `tuple`), that's why I was thinking the `Dialect` approach might work.

Comment: Great answer, though. Just for a slightly different problem ;P

Comment: sub-classing array might work, check the updated answer. Havent tested it though.

Comment: How would I use that? Is it possible to register that as a global thing that the postgresql dialect will use by default?